# Есть ли в python способ выделить передаваемое сообщение?

Tags: python, сокет

При написании чата(просто для практики) столкнулся с тем, что надо передавать от сервера каждому клиенту сообщение с информацией для самой проги, но не для пользователя(ключ для шифрования). Из-за этого он должен выделяться из общей массы сообщений, которые приходят с сервера в клиент. Как это можно реализовать?(чат пишется на сокетах с использованием upd).

Comment: python тут ни при чём, всё зависит от прикладного протокола, который вы используете или изобретаете. Как именно выделять — решать вам

Comment: то есть отсылать его надо будет обычным socket.sento(), а как выделить это уже от моей фантазии зависит, верно?

Comment: Например первый байт блока данных может быть управляющим. Если ни один из битов не установлен, то это сообщение одного пользователя другому. Если установлен старший бит - ключ шифрования. И т.п.

Comment: ок, спасибо большое